# Can we add the elements at specific positions in the existing xml file using DOM parser?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Iam new to DOM parsing, their is a requirement of adding the elements at specific positions in the existing xml file using DOM parser. We will get the positions and element names which are to be added, from the properties file, as shown

```
abc.properties

3 = X
4 = Y
6 = Z
```

The output xml file after adding X,Xchild,Y and Z elements, is as shown

```
 demo.xml  

 <root>
   <A>text</A>
   <B>text</B>
   <X>
      <Xchild>text</Xchild>
   </X>
   <Y>text</Y>
   <C>text</C>
   <Z>text</Z>
 </root>
```

Please suggest me that how can we do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am just wondering how you will maintain the consistency of the positions with the growing number of elements in the document as you are adding new node.

Comment: Thank you for your response. And is their any alternative solution which can solve the given requirement?

Comment: The actual requirement is to add the elements after another existing elements same as shown in the above given output xml. But those elements which are to be added should get from the properties file only. Here, the code which we write should handle any properties file to add elements into the existing xml file. After searching in the internet, i found that we can add elements using "appendChild()" and "insertBefore()" methods only  instead of positions.  Here, my question is, how to take elements as key-value pairs instead of positions in properties file?

Comment: Bhaskar: although DOM can traverse document and locate certain element, it is not supposed to do that. Your problem could be solved by using XPath which is excellent at locating specific element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample of what you may do:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class AddElementFromProp {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
      XPathExpressionException, TransformerException, TransformerConfigurationException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("demo.xml");
    //The XPath part.
    XPathFactory xfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xfactory.newXPath();

    Node result = (Node)xpath.evaluate("/root/*[position()='3']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    Element toInsert = doc.createElement("X");
    result.getParentNode().insertBefore(toInsert, result);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    result = (Node)xpath.evaluate("/root/*[position()='4']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    toInsert = doc.createElement("Y");
    Text txt = doc.createTextNode("text");
    toInsert.appendChild(txt);
    result.getParentNode().insertBefore(toInsert, result);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    result = (Node)xpath.evaluate("/root/*[position()='5']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    toInsert = doc.createElement("Z");
    txt = doc.createTextNode("text");
    toInsert.appendChild(txt);
    result.getParentNode().appendChild(toInsert);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    result = (Node)xpath.evaluate("/root/X", doc, XPathConstants.NODE); //If you know the name of the node
    //result = (Node)xpath.evaluate("/root/*[position()='3']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);//If you know the position of the node
    toInsert = doc.createElement("xchild");
    txt = doc.createTextNode("text");
    toInsert.appendChild(txt);
    result.appendChild(toInsert);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Write out the final xml file
    // Use a Transformer for output
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult _result = new StreamResult("demo1.xml");
    transformer.transform(source, _result);
  }
}
```

**Note**: This is far from a robust solution (just for your reference). There is a bunch of assumptions here. No check has been done to any extent - such as is there already an element at the specific position? Is it the position for the last element? etc.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><A>text</A><B>text</B><C>text</C></root>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root><A>text</A><B>text</B><X><xchild>text</xchild></X><Y>text</Y><C>text</C><Z>text</Z>root>
```

**Update:** added code to insert grand children.

Comment: Thank you so much @dragon66. The given sample code is working like charm. I have modified the code and used, in which it meets the requirement.

Comment: It works fine if all the elements are direct childs under <root> tag. But, now, i want to add the element under another child elements. For instance an xml --- <ParentRoot:xyz xmlns:abc="http://some url">  <ChildRoot> <A>text</A> <B>text</B> <ADD_NEW_ELEMENT_HERE>text</ADD_NEW_ELEMENT_HERE> </item></ChildRoot>, Please guide me @dragon66 how to take XPATH to do this.

Comment: @Bhaskar: I updated the code which should give a rough idea of what can be done in this situation.

Comment: I would like to vote your answer but, i don't have sufficient reputation to do it. Anyhow you helped me a lot. Thank you @dragon66.