# How to selectively merge two xml files in java

Tags: java, xml, merge

I have two XML files (source and destination) and want to selectively merge parts of the source into the destination, using Java. The files have the same structure, but includes nested tags that have identical names at different levels (example below).

The source and destination can have multiple `/Root/folders/folder` I want to select from source (with a specified caption) and merge that with whatever is in destination. If the destination already has content, it must not be overwritten; the source content must be added. In the example below, the result would contain a `<folder caption="TestBlock" description="desc" moniker="">` with multiple `<folders>`

I'm not expert in either Java or XML (but the boss said do it, so ...).

Googling has shown many examples of doing a straight append from file A to file B, where there are no complicated nesting structures but these do not address my problem.

Source File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root signature="{9252F941}" version="11.40">
    <folders>
        <folder caption="TestBlock" description="desc" moniker="">
            <folders>
                <folder caption="tb_insert" description="desc" moniker="">
                    <folders>
                        <folder caption="000_Test" description="desc" moniker="">
                            <references>
                                <ref key="{somekey}" />
                            </references>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                    <references>
                        <ref key="{somekey}" />
                    </references>
                </folder>
            </folders>
        </folder>
        <folder caption="AnotherBlock" description="desc" moniker="">
            <folders>
                <folder caption="abc" description="desc" moniker="">
                    <references>
                        <ref key="{somekey}" />
                    </references>
                </folder>
            </folders>
        </folder>
    </folders>
</Root>
```

Destination file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root signature="{9252F941}" version="11.40">
    <folders>
        <folder caption="Core" description="desc" moniker="" />
        <folder caption="TestBlock" description="desc" moniker="">
            <folders>
                <folder caption="000_Temp" description="desc" moniker="">
                    <folders>
                        <folder caption="000_Temp2" description="desc" moniker="">
                            <references>
                                <ref key="{somekey}" />
                            </references>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                </folder>
            </folders>
            <references>
                <ref key="{somekey}" />
            </references>
        </folder>
    </folders>
</Root>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root signature="{9252F941}" version="11.40">
    <folders>
        <folder caption="Core" description="desc" moniker="" />
        <folder caption="TestBlock" description="desc" moniker="">
            <folders>
                <folder caption="tb_insert" description="desc" moniker="">
                    <folders>
                        <folder caption="000_Test" description="desc" moniker="">
                            <references>
                                <ref key="{somekey}" />
                            </references>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                    <references>
                        <ref key="{somekey}" />
                    </references>
                </folder>
            </folders>
            <folders>
                <folder caption="000_Temp" description="desc" moniker="">
                    <folders>
                        <folder caption="000_Temp2" description="desc" moniker="">
                            <references>
                                <ref key="{somekey}" />
                            </references>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                </folder>
            </folders>
            <references>
                <ref key="{somekey}" />
            </references>
        </folder>
    </folders>
</Root>
```

Any help (noob level, please) would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we add the elements at specific positions in the existing xml file using DOM parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758565/can-we-add-the-elements-at-specific-positions-in-the-existing-xml-file-using-dom)

Comment: I can't figure out how you merge the nodes. Elaborate a bit more the rule for this _merge_.

Comment: I don't have a schema.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the duplicate.

Comment: In the example given, the destination of the merge is the tag folder where caption = TestBlock. The source is the content of the tag folder where caption = TestBlock. Basically I want to take everything in caption=TestBlock from source to the same location in destination.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've specified the requirements fully (one example does not make a specification), but if we assume that the first source document contains exactly one `/Root/folders/folder` and that its content is to replace the one-and-only `//folder` in the destination document that has a matching caption, then the logic can be written in XSLT 3.0 as

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:variable name="replacement" select="doc('source.xml')/Root/folders/folder"/>
    <xsl:template match="folder[@caption = $replacement/$caption]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$replacement"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

and you can run this from Java using the Saxon library with the code:

```
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
Xslt30Transformer trans = comp.compile("stylesheet.xsl").load30();
Serailizer out = proc.newSerializer(new File("output.xml"));
trans.applyTemplates(new StreamSource("destination.xml"), out);
```

If you prefer to use the XSLT 1.0 processor that comes with the JDK then that's possible too, it will just require a little bit more code. It will still be a lot less code than trying to do it directly with the low-level DOM API.

Comment: The source and destination can have multiple `/Root/folders/folder` I want to select from source (with a specified caption) and merge that with whatever is in destination. If the destination already has content, it must not be overwritten; the source content must be added. In the example above, the result would contain a `<folder caption="TestBlock" description="desc" moniker="" />` with multiple `<folders>`

Comment: Then please update your question with a more complete specification of the problem, and update your test example to (a) give greater coverage of the requirement and (b) get rid of some of the irrelevant detail.